# Where are the menu items located?

Tags: menu

I am using Linux Mint 18 Sarah with Cinnamon. I have a problem where I have menu category items in the menu that won't be removed. I tried deleting them through the menu configuration and they won't delete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The menu-entries are files with the ending .desktop. they are locatet in /home/user/.local/share/applications/ and /usr/share/applications. A example from me

```
ls -al .local/share/applications/ | grep mpv
-rw-r--r--  1 alex alex  2061 Sep 28 19:54 mpv.desktop
-rw-r--r--  1 alex alex   253 Sep 12 00:18 mpv-dvd.desktop
```

greetings Bahamut